# Keep the order while grouping in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following table in MSSQL with data (simplified for example).

```
---------
|id|Data|
---------
|1 |XOO |
|2 |OXO |
|3 |OOX |
|4 |XOO |
|5 |OXO |
|6 |OOX |
|7 |XXX |
|8 |OOO |
```

(Data row 1,2,3 repeats again at 4,5,6. 7 and 8 are unique again.
I want to retreive the following using count and group by:

```
------------ (desired result)
|Count|Data|
------------
|2    |XOO |
|2    |OXO |
|2    |OOX |
|1    |XXX |
|1    |OOO |
```

The order (id) is very important. When I run the following query, I can get the count values but the order seems messed up.

```
SELECT  COUNT ([Data]) AS Count, [Data]
FROM [MyTable]  GROUP BY [Data] 

------------ (incorrect result with wrong order)
|Count|Data|
------------
|2    |XOO |
|1    |OOO |
|2    |OOX |
|1    |OXO |
|1    |XXX |
```

I this related to the Query or maybe the table structure?

Comment: Add min(id) to your select and order by using it

Comment: Indeed.. it seemed that simple. Thanks! Can I select this as an answer?

Comment: @JamesZ You can order by an expression without it being in your `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order by the minimum id:

```
SELECT COUNT([Data]) AS Count, [Data]
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY [Data] 
ORDER BY MIN(ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to `ORDER BY Count DESC,[Data] DESC` like so:

```
SELECT  COUNT ([Data]) AS Count, [Data]
FROM [MyTable]  
GROUP BY [Data] 
ORDER BY Count DESC,[Data] DESC
```

The results:

[image]